# ProgressRing never shows

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have created a page, in which I have placed inside the `Grid` the above:

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="Ring" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

But when I do `Ring.IsActive = true;` in my code nothing happens! Possibly I am missing something very simple here, but I can't find out what it is.

This is my xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Diakopes_v2._0.AddExpense"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Diakopes_v2._0"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Background="#FF0277BD">
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Accept" Click="Accept_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Cancel" Label="Cancel" Click="Cancel_Click"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0277BD" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE1F5FE" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>

        <TextBlock Text="New Expense" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="46" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/BebasNeue Bold.ttf#Bebas Neue"></TextBlock>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="564" Margin="0,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400">
            <TextBox x:Name="Name" PlaceholderText="Name"></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="Price" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="Price"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="Ring" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and this is my .cs method were I want to use the `ProgressRing`:

```
private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Ring.IsActive = true;
    Name.Text = Name.Text.Trim();
    Price.Text = Price.Text.Trim();

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper();

    Price.Text = Price.Text.Replace(",", ".");
    ExpensesTable NewExpense = new ExpensesTable(Place.Id, Name.Text, Convert.ToSingle(Price.Text));
    dbHelper.InsertExpense(NewExpense);

    Ring.IsActive = false;

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Expenses), Place.Name);
}
```

Comment: where are you doing the Ring.IsActive=true? Did you try to remove the IsEnabled?

Comment: the code is working fine. there is some other problem in your code.

Comment: Check these 3 things: 1) The size of the Ring, maybe it is has 0 width or length 2) It may be behind another control 3) It may be off screen

Comment: I have checked these things and the weird thing is that when I use a progressBar (and of course remove the Ring.IsActive = true;) it works fine.

Comment: please, provide sample with problem or full code of your `xaml`

Comment: @Andrii Krupka I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just created sample with code that you provided with simple modifications:

Turn on:

```
private void Accept_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Ring.IsActive = true;
}
```

Turn off:

```
private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Ring.IsActive = false;
}
```

Look at the screenshot from emulator:

[image]

Also, to remove black rect, you should change `Background` property to `Transparent`

So, I guess your code works so fast that you haven't time to see how works `ProgressRing`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice with the Background property. I think I found the problem with the ProgressRing. It might be that I am not communicating asynchronously with my database.